# how erosion works in mathematical morphology?

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory, analysis, computer-vision

I have these definitions:

Let $A \subset E^N$ and $b \in E^N$. The translation of $A$ by $b$, denoted by $(A)_{b r}$ is defined as
$$
(A)_b=\left\{c \in E^N \mid c=a+b \quad \text { for some } a \in A\right\}
$$

and

The binary erosion of $A$ by $B$, denoted by $A \ominus_b B$, is defined as
$$
A \ominus_b B=\left\{x \in E^N \mid x+b \in A \quad \text { for every } b \in B\right\} .
$$
Equivalently, we may write
$$
A \ominus_b B=\bigcap_{b \in B}(A)_{-b} .
$$
and i have this example:
\begin{aligned}
& A A=\{(0,1),(1,1),(2,1),(2,2),(3,0)\} \\
& B=\{(0,0),(0,1)\} \\
& A \ominus_b B=\{(2,1)\}
\end{aligned}

I am trying to make another example of the following
\begin{aligned}
& A =\{(0,2),(0,3),(1,2),(1,3),(2,2),(2,3),(3,0),(3,1 ),(3,2),(3,3),(3,4)\} \\
& B=\{(0,0),(1,0),(2,0)\} \\
& A \ominus_b B
\end{aligned}
but its not same than this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rP1KZb3llCY) and i am desperate